# UITextView scrolling enabled = invisible text?

Tags: ios, xcode, scroll, uitextview

I have a view in my `storyboard` with some items, 1 of which is a `UITextView`. Whenever I enable scrolling (either by inspector or via code), the `UITextView` disappears/becomes invisible/whatever. Is there a way to make this not happen?

Thanks in advance

Comment: probably you have lots of whitespaces and thats why it is invisible ? are there autolayout constraints attached to it ?

Comment: I have constraints for "spacing to nearest neighbour". And except for spaces between words, there are no odd whitespaces. It just shows whenever I disable scrolling

Comment: can u see it view debugger ? Also post a screenshot of your textview and its constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height of `UITextView` is probably not set. When scrolling is disabled, the `UITextView`'s size is calculated based on it's content (because the content has to fit, because if it doesn't, user can't scroll to see it). On the other hand, when the scrolling is enabled, the system presumes, that even if the content doesn't fit, user can scoll down to see it all. And since the `UITextView` height is not set by you, and neither it is set "by the content", the `UITextView` height is `0`.

Comment: I indeed forgot to set the bottom-constraints, which doesn't give it a height. It all sounds logical when you think about it.

Comment: how do you think this can be solved, because i want the textview scrolling to be disabled until the height grows above 200. If i set a height initially (say 200) it would just be 200 (which is too much) until someone starts typing before it adjusts back based on the content.

Comment: @OluwatobiOmotayo, that should probably be a separate question :) A bit broad for a comment.